# Is it possible to configure Okular to open a given file at the position where it was closed?

Tags: linux, kde, okular

I am using Kile + Okular to create Latex documents. Okular has a nice feature that if you open the same document again, it will go to the same position as it was last closed. However, it can detect if the file was changed - and goes to the beginning if this is the case.

Is it possible to go to the previous position even if the file has changed? In my particular use-case I often change a few symbols in an equation and want to see the same page after recompilation - but its not the case by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post will not answer your actual question, however may help you achieving what you want.
First you have to once set "Settings/Configure Okular/General/Program Features/Reload document on file change" in Okular.

Then compile your LaTex file and open the result in Okular. If you want to change something don't close okular. Just switch to kile, edit, recompile, switch back to okular. You should arrive on the same page(number) in the recompiled document.

Comment: Annoyingly, if your workflow requires you to perform two compilation cycles, the first of which reduces the number of pages to a small constant value, then okular will not jump to the correct page number after the second compilation. Both atril and evince handle these cases more sensibly.